# What's the meaning of hard code query

Tags: mysql, terminology

can you explain what meaning of hard code query? i'm newbie
 like this query:

Query :

```
SELECT Nama,
SUM(case when motor='vario' then 1 else 0 end) vario,
SUM(case when motor='beat' then 1 else 0 end) beat,
SUM(case when motor='supra'then 1 else 0 end) supra,
SUM(case when motor='megapro'then 1 else 0 end) megapro,
SUM(case when motor='cb150'then 1 else 0 end) cb150
FROM matrixreport
GROUP by Nama;
```

Is it hard code?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems working well. In software development, "hard code" or "hard coding" can be interpreted as "embedding your external data like SQL statement directly to your source code".

Reference:

[Hard coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding)

[Soft coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softcoding)